# How to overlay a green color on the right of my animation?

Tags: compositing-nodes

so i have rendered a scene and i want to add a color to 50% of the screen like this:

[image]

This is how i can do it in the VSE.

But is this also possible via compositor?

Sorry, my compositor knowledge is pretty limited....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use box mask for this and add color using color mix:

[image]

Comment: i knew it must work somehow...thanks!!!